# compilation error while using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

Source Error:


Line 45: BeginContext("~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml", 0, 4199, true);
Line 46: 
Line 47: WriteLiteral("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +
Line 48: "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +
Line 49: "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +
```

Comment: Are you doing anything different in the layout page ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@` symbol to your string beginnings to ignore any escape sequences. This is because the `\` is an escape character, a double `\\` is one literal `\` character, but having an odd number of `\` like this will throw an exception like the one you received. The easiest way around it is to use @ which tells the compiler treat all characters as literals, there are no escapes.

```
WriteLiteral(@"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +
@"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +
@"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +
```